# Proving $M$ has a unique topology s.t. each $\phi_\alpha$ is a homeomorphism onto its image; and in this topology, $M$ is a top. manifold.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds

Can someone please help me with the following problem? I understand why these conditions are necessary, however, I am having difficulties grasping the uniqueness component. Doesn't it just stem from the homeomorphism that we get from $\phi$?

Let $M$ be a set, and suppose we have a collection of subsets $U_\alpha \subset M$ and injections $\phi\colon U_\alpha \to \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying:

(a) For each $\alpha, \phi_\alpha(U_\alpha)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

(b) For each $\alpha, \beta, \phi_\alpha(U_\alpha \cap U_\beta)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

(c) If $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \ne \emptyset, \phi_\beta \cap \phi_\alpha^{-1}\colon \phi_\alpha(U_\alpha\cap U_\beta) \to \phi_\beta(U_\alpha \cap U_\beta)$ is a continuous bijection.

(d) $M$ is the union of countably many $U_\alpha$.

(e) For any $p,q \in M$, either there exists some $U_\alpha$ containing both $p$ and $q$, or there exist disjoint $U_\alpha, U_\beta$ with $p\in U_\alpha$ and $q\in U_\beta$.

Prove that $M$ has a unique topology such that each $\phi_\alpha$ is a homeomorphism onto its image; and in this topology, $M$ is a topological manifold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in fact false that the topology is unique.  For instance, let $M=\mathbb{Q}$ and let the $U_\alpha$ be all the singleton subsets of $M$, with $\phi_\alpha:U_\alpha\to\mathbb{R}^0$ the unique map for each $\alpha$.  Then this satisfies all your hypotheses, but any topology at all on $M$ makes each $\phi_\alpha$ a homeomorphism to its image.

For the topology to be unique, you need to additionally require that each $U_\alpha$ is open in the topology.  Since the $U_\alpha$ cover $M$, this implies a set $U\subseteq M$ is open iff $U\cap U_\alpha$ is open in $U_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$.  But we know which subsets of $U_\alpha$ are open since $\phi_\alpha$ is a homeomorphism, so the topology is uniquely determined.

Comment: Thank you, Eric!